# How to create a reference line between a name and a value in LibreOffice

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer

In the figure (which is a part of the table of contents of some book) the doted lines help our eyes to easily spot the page number of the mentioned chapter.

When creating similar contents using LibreOffice, how can I create the doted lines easily without typing every dots manually?

[image]

Comment: What version of LibreOffice are you using. It by-default inserts those dots for me in LibreOffice v4.2.3.

Comment: I am using 4.2.2.1 & I don't think there will be a feature different between these 2 versions. I think I am missing something. Do you refer automatically creating table of contents? (I refer manually creating that)

Comment: Yes, I am creating the Table of Contents using Insert menu >> Indexes and Tables >> Indexes and Tables >> Index/Table Tab >> Ok.